# C# Ask for Domain Admin credential and use them to perform some task

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

I need some help with examples how to use Credential of a current user running application.
So in windows 7 you can run application using user loged in by simply running application or you can use "Run as a different User" option and run it as another user.

In my Active Directory I have 2 account Domain User and one with Domain Admin rights. I'm login Windows as a Domain User and when I need I'm using "Run as a different User" to launch some task as a Domain Admin.

So the task is to get my Credential and use it to perform some task, lets say rename active directory user name.
Best way to do this as I can see is to ask user running application to enter Domain Admin credential on then start application and use them for various task. Of course I can easily run application with "Run as a different User" but I still need to get this credential and use them.

I've searched through the web and I can't find this, all i could find is using credential for a web auth.

**If you can show me some examples how to:**

1) Ask user for a Admin user credential ( i can leave without this )

2) **Get and use credentials of a user running application**

I don't want to know password I know I can't. Don't really want to add to a WPF form password box I prefer to use windows API to handle this i've already entered user name and password using "Run as a different User".

PS: I sorry if this topic exists :( I guess I'm bad at creating correct search requests.

**ADDED:** to be more clear what I need. In powershell it will look like this:

```
# This Asks user to enter credentials
$cred = Get-Credential; 
# this checks if I have rights to use them.
Get-ADDomain “DOMAIN” –Server “Domain.com” –Credential $cred;
```

Of course it's simplified as hell though the point is that I can use credentials user entered when ever it's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent C# to your `Get-ADDomain` is quite simple, it is just

```
public void PerformSomeActionAsAdmin(string adminUsername, string adminPassword)
{
    //Null causes the constructor to connect to the current domain the machine is on.
    //                                                                       |
    //                                                                       V
     using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, adminUsername, adminPassword))
    {
        //do something here with ctx, the operations will be performed as whoever's username and password you passed in.
    }
}
```

if you don't want to connect to the current domain and instead want to connect to `Domain.com` then replace the `null` with the appropriate string.

**EDIT:** if you want to use secure strings you can't use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext`, you will need to go with the lower level calls in `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`. Doing this process is quite complex, here is a link to the MSDN article "[Introduction to System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (S.DS.P)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx) explaining how to use it. It is a big complex read and honestly I don't think it is worth it to be able to use encrypted strings.

```
public void PerformSomeActionAsAdmin(NetworkCredential adminCredential)
{
    using(LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection("fabrikam.com", adminCredential))
    {
       // MAGIC
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do :) I don't really want to use password as a string I prefer to use SucureString if possible. Thought if I wont find a way to do this I will just add Usertextbox and Passwordbox(with dots) so user could be able to type credential as a plain text.

Comment: There is no point in using SecureString if you are not using a API that does not accept a secure string. Neither `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` nor `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext` support secure strings. Also, think about this: To be able to get the string from the program and it was not a secure string you must be able to stop and debug the program. If I was a domain admin and a user suddenly stops and starts debugging the program I just entered my password in to I would be quite suspicious. So, what is using SecureString protecting you from?

Comment: @BolnoYGaD Well I found how to do it, but it is ugly and complicated and I don't think it is worth it.

Comment: Mostly I want to login into Application using NTLM, so my application will use credentials I've entered to perform its task. This program is not for Domain Users it's for Domain Admins. I want a my partners login with their Credential not with Admninistrator or my creds. Thats the only reason I'm talking bout securestring. As far i understood most of my need will need password as a string. So i should stop wasting time and just use NameTextbox And PassWordbox.

Comment: Yeah i've seen this article thats one of the reasons i've came here i was pretty shure there should be easier way to do this. Ok i think i will stop looking for an easy way to use this. I'll use strings. I guess ill mark ur post as an answer. Thank you for your time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check if the current user is a doman admin?  start by looking at his code, it should help you get started identifying what AD groups the current user is in.  This will give you a list of strings that are each group's name the current user belongs to.  Then you can check that list against whatever AD group you are trying to check for.  Replace YourDomain with your domain name:

```
WindowsIdentity wi = WindowIdentity.GetCurrent();

List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (IdentityReference group in wi.Groups)
                    {
                        result.Add(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString().Replace("YourDomain\\", String.Empty));
                    }
```

Since i'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, this also might be helpful.  You'd have to get the user name and password from a textobx, password box etc.  This could be used for an "override" to use, for example, a manager's credentials etc. to do something the current user wasn't allowed to do because of AD group membership etc.

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YourDomain"))
                {
                    if (UserName.Contains("YourDomain\\"))
                    {
                        UserName = UserName.Replace("YourDomain\\", String.Empty);
                    }
                    //validate the credentials
                   bool IsValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(UserName, Password);
                }
```

Comment: I want something like this CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials() function does. 1) When user runs application he is asked to enter domain admin credetials in Windows 7 native style 2) When he entered i need to check if he has domain admin rights and on true run display application WPF form with so he can do domain admin job :) using credentials he entered.